# IE10 flexbox alignment issues

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-10

I have a problem with the usage of flexbox in IE10 demonstrated in this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q49Lfbkg/4/

Now the first and second span should be left aligned and the third one right aligned. This works fine in other browsers but IE10 seems to ignore the grow property.

I've already looked into the [flexbugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs) but I couldn't find anything applicable to my situation.

```css
div {
  display: -ms-flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.second {
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="first">First</span>
  <span class="second">Second</span>
  <span class="third">Third</span>
</div>
```

Is there a workaround for this issue or should I just not use flexbox?

Comment: What do you mean by `grow` property?

Comment: flex-grow or the 1st parameter of the flex property

Comment: It's already included

Comment: Find some advice on IE10 here: https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/